# Why does Sorbet think that a method I provided an explicit signature for in an RBI file doesn't exist?

Tags: ruby, geokit, sorbet

One of my classes depends on the gem Geokit, which doesn't provide an RBI file of its own nor is it included in the `sorbet-typed` repo. I hand-wrote a couple RBI files for it myself, including signatures for the methods that I use in my own code.

When I attempt to change the class that depends on Geokit to `typed: true`, it complains that the methods I'm using don't exist.

The class typechecks fine under `typed: false`.

**geokit.rbi**

```rb
# typed: strong

module Geokit
end
```

**bounds.rbi**

```rb
# typed: strong

class Geokit::Bounds
    sig do
        params(
            thing: T.any(Geokit::Bounds, T::Array[T.any(T::Array[Numeric], Numeric, String)], String, Geokit::LatLng),
            other: T.nilable(T.any(T::Array[Numeric], String, Geokit::LatLng))
        ).returns(Geokit::Bounds)
    end
    def normalize(thing, other = nil); end
end
```

**lib/platform/x.rb**

```rb
class X
  BOUNDS = Geokit::Bounds.normalize([[0.8852118e2, -0.751305e1], [0.689324e2, -0.386637e1]])
end
```

The error I get is as follows:

```
lib/platform/x.rb:2: Method normalize does not exist on T.class_of(Geokit::Bounds) https://srb.help/7003
     2 |  BOUNDS = Geokit::Bounds.normalize([[0.8852118e2, -0.751305e1], [0.689324e2, -0.386637e1]])
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  Autocorrect: Use `-a` to autocorrect
    lib/platform/x.rb:2: Replace with initialize
     2 |  BOUNDS = Geokit::Bounds.normalize([[0.8852118e2, -0.751305e1], [0.689324e2, -0.386637e1]])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `self.` in the RBI definition of that method. Sorbet thinks that `normalize` is an instance method on `Bounds`.

```rb
# typed: strong

class Geokit::Bounds
    sig do
        params(
            thing: T.any(Geokit::Bounds, T::Array[T.any(T::Array[Numeric], Numeric, String)], String, Geokit::LatLng),
            other: T.nilable(T.any(T::Array[Numeric], String, Geokit::LatLng))
        ).returns(Geokit::Bounds)
    end
    def self.normalize(thing, other = nil); end
end
```